# Can't find Magento attributes for Custom Export module

Tags: module, custom-options, csv, export

Downloaded and installed the Custom Export module from Connect, and works fine.  However I want to add some include some more fields in the exported CSV.

Currently, the template CSV file looks like this:

```
order.increment_id|order.status|order.created_at|customer.name|customer.email|customer.taxvat|address.street_1|address.street_2|address.street_3|address.street_4|address.city|address.region|address.postcode|address.telephone|order.shipping_description
```

I also want to include the shipping address customer name (because if they purchase as a Guest, the [customer.name] field is blank. The attributes I want to include are as below:

- Shipping Customer Name (as mentioned)
- Weight
- Shipping Arrival Date
- Order Value
- Additional instructions / comments

These all seem to be the built-in Magento attributes and aren't visible or configurable in the Manage Attributes panel, which is understandable, but it does mean I can't easily find the code for these.

I've tried searching for a list of the standard built in attributes codes, but nothing helpful came up.

If anyone can tell me what codes I need to add, or give me a clue where I can find them, that would be seriously appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway with a bit of trial and error i pretty much found what I was looking for.  For other users reference, the extension is "Custom Export Order to CSV" by Lema 21.

The `order.increment_id` is a 2 part query - the "increment_id" part is the attribute and the "order" part seems to be the category of the attribute.

I was able to find out the other attributes I wanted by opening the MySQL database connected to Magento and pick out the attributes I wanted to include on the export.  Once I had found the code for the shipping arrival date attribute for instance, I appended "order." to the beginning of the attribute to include the attribute value in the report.  Some were a bit of trial and error as I had to test whether the prefix was "address.", "order.", "customer." or whatever.

Got there in the end and hope this helps someone else!